# Re-learning HTML

Tags: css, html

I've been in the industry for many years, however for the last 10 years I haven't had to do much of the HTML myself. I've recently become the only developer at work and as such I have to do all of the HTML myself as well.

Normally this wouldn't be an issue, however I'm trying to stick with the same quality standards that I have for my PHP / MySQL / JavaScript / jQuery work that I do. So tables are definitely out of the question (the last time I had to write HTML/CSS myself was when nested tables was acceptable).

I've been toying around with HTML `div`s and CSS and I'm having some pretty major issues with it, and not finding much of anything online other than the crap posted at [W3Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) doesn't help either.

Let's first take a look at some code I'm working on, here's the HTML:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: gray;
}

#page_wrapper {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    width: 980px;
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    height: 160px;
    width: 980px;
    background: blue;
}

#content-wrapper {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: -120px;
    width: 980px;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link href="inc/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page_wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <header>this is the header...</header>
                <div id="content-wrapper">sdasd</div>
                <footer>
                    this is the footer
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've attempted several variations of this, and I haven't been able to get it to look the way that it should. Note that I'm using background colors specifically to tell the positioning of everything because this is more of a learning exercise than a real-world example.

Many of the pages that I will have to create will have a background image in the body just like many websites these days. Then the content will be 980 pixels wide. My big problem with the code above, is that the content-wrapper `div`, needs to be 100% of the available space if the content isn't long enough to push it down.

When I add `height: 100%` to that declaration in the CSS it seems to render it just fine however it puts it to 100% of the window which makes it overlap the `page_wrapper` `div` that contains it.

I'd like to not use `overflow` declarations at all, as for some reason every time I do it screws everything else up.

So I guess the real question and/or request here would be:

- How do I do what I would like to do in the above code?

Comment: Consider a framework like Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) as a starting point (or 960 or one of the others).  It will help you get to a finished product sooner and it will give you an solid learning reference for what's possible.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ > w3schools

Comment: [Garbage is right](http://w3fools.com). I get the feeling that this question is a bit broad...and even though you narrow it down at the end, there *are* two separate questions. Consider splitting this up and perhaps being more specific.

Comment: problem of using a framework, and believe me i've looked at many is that you don't actually learn how to do it...  So while a framework is a great idea in theory, many of the sites that I'll be building are 1 page marketing sites that will follow pretty much the exact coding as above...  

so framework i think not really plausible in this situation..

Comment: It seems that even posts that outright acknowledge W3Schools' suckery can't escape from the obligatory W3Fools noise... and no, garbage is not right. *That's why it's called garbage!*

Comment: @boltClock this is helpful how?  I mean afterall, it's not the fault of anyone but the makers of w3schools themselves that they have the reputation of idiots..  They suck, they will always suck..  sure I don't know HTML and CSS as well as I should for todays standards, but thats why i've come here to learn off this basic html sample and get links to any other resources people find helpful on the subject in question..  w3schools, while using this technique also has JS, and CSS inside their pages.  no external stylesheets, and people trust this? what a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
background: gray;
}

#page_wrapper {
background: yellow;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#content {
width: 980px;
background: white;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
height: 160px;
width: 980px;
background: blue;
}

#content-wrapper {
background: green;
height: 100%;
position:relative;
}

footer {
height: 120px;
width: 980px;
background: orange;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page_wrapper">
    <div id="content">            
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <header>this is the header...</header>
            test
            <footer>this is the footer</footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've added position:relative to #content and it did nothing.  I added it to the #content-wrapper and it worked, but it's still 100% of the window itself and it completely hides the footer...

Comment: This is what I see (latest FireFox): http://screencast.com/t/u1g7kwXmgABD  Not what you were expecting?

Comment: definately not what i'm expecting..  the orange is the footer.. should be at the bottom..  (if we're going with the css i have above).. there should be a giant green div of emptiness between the blue and the orange.. where all 3 of which make up 100% of the browser height

Comment: Check updated.  You needed a wrapper div to have the content in the middle be the right height automatically and the footer always be at the bottom.

Comment: Okay, so this looks a lot closer to what I was needing...  other than the header and footer having the 960px width too..  now..  suppose just for a moment.. that i want to use something similar to this, but have the the green box have no background color...  and create a div around the content body which in this case is 'test' with a white background.. that has a margin of 5 on top and bottom..  but has the 100% height of that entire area that is now currently green...

Comment: also, with the position: absolute; on the footer element, it forces that to be there..  having it attached to the bottom of the div content is surrounded by is more ideal, because when there is a page with more content than a single browser page can display, the footer will be forced down instead of staying at the very bottom of the browser page.

Comment: If you want it to always be 100% of the page height for all 3 containers, you'll have to assign % heights to the divs.  It's NOT a table.

Answer (score -1):

The body tag is already "100% of the available space if the content isn't long enough to push it down."

So just use that element for anything you need (background images, etc). Take a look at CSS properties such as `background-position` to control where something is visible inside the `<body>` tag.

Otherwise, I would go for `min-height: 100%;` on the wrapper but am not sure how compatible that is with older versions of IE. And it may or may not do funky things on a touchscreen devices.

In general however, HTML is not very good at vertical layout. Especially in relation to the browser window's height. Most of the issues can be worked around in modern browsers, but it's better to simply accept this constraint and design your website around the assumption that you have no control over the height. It's just not worth the headache.

Comment: Seriously? You should be thankful someone who has worked on literally thousands of websites offered to help you learn. I'm not going to waste any more of my time here with you.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the page wrapper or content div. You can just set the body width to 980px. You can also set your html and body to whatever color you want.

While W3Schools has gotten a deservedly bad rap, they've cleaned up quite a bit and aren't a bad, quick reference.

Comment: With background images and such that I'll be using frequently, none of this helpful...

body: background images, width must be 100% for a fluid width look.

no page_wrapper: means no header background image that again, is full width.

no content div, means page is also 100% not 980 like preferred in this case..

will my syntax change overtime? yes i'm sure it will, but these suggestions aren't really helpful.

Comment: @Justin - Why do you think you can't have background images on those elements or be full width? Why do you think the body won't contain those elements to 980 as you wish?

Comment: the body element will keep it as 980 or 960, etc..  however if i set the width of body to 960px or 980px or any variation of less than 100%.. when you have a background image under the body {} declaration in CSS, it too would be limited to that width.

Comment: @Justin - Then put the image in the `<html>` element or use absolute positioning. (I need to re-read the requirement)

Comment: Okay, so say I have a body background image and add that to my html tag like you propose.  When I also have a 2nd image for a header-background to span 100% width of the page.. how do you propose I do that with a body set to 980px and no other element other than the html tag at 100% width?  Your solution is invalid...